# Paypal - Recurring payments with checkout.js

Tags: paypal, checkout, billing

Is it possible to trigger recurring payments (subscriptions / billing agreements) using checkout.js?

If so, can you please provide a working example?

Comment: Seems like it's possible if your app uses `payment(...)` to call out to your server, from which your server calls a PayPal REST api to create a billing agreement and returns a specific token. See the following question on GitHub: https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout/issues/131

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible. I just created a POC for this.

1. Create a BillingPlan and activate it

   ```
   plan = Plan.new(PlanAttributes)
   plan.create 
   patch = Patch.new
   patch.op = "replace"
   patch.path = "/";
   patch.value = { :state => "ACTIVE" }
   plan.update( patch )
   ```
2. inside the payment function of paypal.Button call your server to create a BillingAgreement. The user will then authorize the payment.

   ```
   agreement = Agreement.new(agreement_attributes)
   agreement.plan =  Plan.new( :id => "<the_plan_id>" )
   agreement.create
   ```
3. inside the onAuthorize function of paypal.Button call your server to execute the BillingAgreement

   ```
   agreement.execute
   ```

Following the example in 
Checkout https://github.com/chibeepatag/paypal_poc